# Weird CSS issue - works fine on Safari, not on Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, safari

So, I decided to make a few changes here and there in my app's webpage. And today I've noticed that something has gone... horribly wrong:

- the page looks fine on Safari
- on Chrome the footer at the bottom looks like a mess (no background, no styling whatsoever...)

**Safari:**

[image: Safari screenshot]

**Chrome:**

[image: Chrome screenshot]

---

**Here's the footer part (PHP/HTML):**

```
    <div id="prefooter">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3" style='text-align:center;'>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url('/category/plugins'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-plug"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Plugins</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3" style='text-align:center;'>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url('/category/themes'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Themes</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3" style='text-align:center;'>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url('/category/blog'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Blog</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3" style='text-align:center;'>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url('/contact-us'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Support</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Here's the CSS/LESS part:**

```
#prefooter {
    background:#555;
    height: 45px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, arial, freesans, clean;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-top:10px;

    a {
      color: #ddd;

      &:hover {
        color: white;
        text-decoration:none;
      }
    }
}
```

---

**Live:** [The actual website](http://osxpeppermint.com)

---

**UPDATE:**

Guys, thanks a lot for your help. However, the culprit was the Cache (and I thought I had cleared it). Going in Incognito mode, miraculously fixed the issue! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my chrome it works. What version of chrome are you using? 
I am using Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit).

**Chrome:**
[image: Chrome]

Comment: Well, that's very weird! Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) (Mac OSX)

Comment: Yes, indeed that is strange.Have you tried deleting your cache en reloading the page?

Comment: Have a look at my update. (I can't understand how I always end up getting tricked by Cache!)

Answer (score 1):

Well i got chrome and It looks like it should do. Sure your chrome hasn't an update to do ?

If that's not it you should know that chrome and mozilla have default value on some stuff. But  normaly it's just anoying for positioning your stuff.

Thoose are the properties :
-o- for Opera
-moz- for Gecko (Mozilla)
-webkit- for Webkit (Chrome, Safari, Android...)
-ms- for Microsoft (Internet Explorer)
-khtml- for KHTML (Konqueror)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, but that's still very weird. Chrome *is* up-to-date. But I'm still seeing it the way it looks in the screenshot!.